# Update every localized boolean attribute value to TRUE

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I have added a new attribute "showFlag" with type="localized:java.lang.Boolean to the itemtype VariantProduct and set default value to TRUE.but for existing variant products the value comes as n/a.
[image]

I would like to update every existing variant products all language(localized) showFlag values  as Yes.How can I do that?

Comment: Using script/flexible query you can iterate over all your model and set true for all locals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update all of them with impex batch mode for fastest way.

```
UPDATE Product[batchmode=true];itemType(code)[unique=true];description[en][default='test']
;Product;
;VariantProduct;
```

Comment: this one seems to be a better method.

Answer (score 2):

The easy solution to do this is using a groovy script something like this,

```
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ModelService;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.FlexibleSearchQuery;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.FlexibleSearchService;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.SearchResult
import de.hybris.platform.variants.jalo.VariantProduct


FlexibleSearchService flexibleSearchService=(FlexibleSearchService)spring.getBean("flexibleSearchService");
ModelService modelService=(ModelService)spring.getBean("modelService");

List<Locale> locals = Arrays.asList(Locale.getAvailableLocales()); 

queryString="Select {pk} from {variantProduct} ";

FlexibleSearchQuery query=new FlexibleSearchQuery(queryString);

SearchResult result=flexibleSearchService.search(query);


List<VariantProduct> products = result.getResult();

for(VariantProduct variantModel : products){

    for (Locale locale : locals){
        variantModel.setShowFlag(Boolean.TRUE,locale);
    }
    modelService.save(variantModel);
}
```

Adapt this code to correspond more to your needs,

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use bean shell and iterate over every language using the i18nService?

Answer (score 0):

the following impex import script worked well for the above problem:

```
UPDATE VariantProduct[batchmode=true];itemtype(code)[unique=true];showFlag[lang=en_GL];showFlag[lang=en_ZA];showFlag[lang=en_CA];showFlag[lang=en_US];showFlag[lang=en_AP];showFlag[lang=en_IN];showFlag[lang=en_CE];showFlag[lang=en_ME];showFlag[lang=en_SG];showFlag[lang=en_AU];showFlag[lang=en_PH];showFlag[lang=en_MA];showFlag[lang=en_GB];

;VariantProduct;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE
```